# Circular Permutation Problem - Confused

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I just came across this permutation question that confused me.

**The question: How many ways are there to arrange 5 girls and 5 boys around a circular table with 10 chairs, assuming: (symmetrical arrangements around the table are identical or in other words, the chairs are identical)**

(a) No restrictions

(b) Boys and girls alternate

---

(a) So there are 10! ways to arrange the 5 boys and girls, assuming each chair is unique. But in this case, all the chairs are identical, so we divide by 10 to eliminate the identical symmetrical circular arrangments. $\frac{10!}{10}=362,880$

(b) *This question is the one that confuses me.* If the boys and girls have to alternate then the number of permutations would be $\underline{5}\times\underline{5}\times\underline{4}\times\underline{4}\times\underline{3}\times\underline{3}\times\underline{2}\times\underline{2}\times\underline{1}\times\underline{1}=5!\times5!=14400$. But in order to account for identical symmetrical circular arrangements, you would have to divide by 10 ---> $\frac{14400}{10} = 1440$.

But apparently the answer is actually 2880, which is double what I got. Can someone explain what was wrong in my logic? I can see if I did $\frac{14400}{5} = 2880$ it would be give the right answer, but I have no reason why.

Comment: Moving on one place isn't a symmetry, it turns boys into girls. You've got to  move on two places, so divide by $5$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician  That should be an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How many ways are there to arrange five boys and five girls around a circular table with ten chairs assuming symmetrical arrangements around the table are identical and boys and girls alternate?

ancientmathematician has explained the flaw in your reasoning in the comments.

Since we only care about the relative order of the people, we can avoid dividing by symmetry arguments by fixing a particular person and counting arrangements relative to her.

Suppose Angela is one of the girls.  Seat her.  Doing so determines which seats are occupied by girls and which seats are occupied by boys.  The other four girls may be seated in $4!$ ways as we proceed clockwise around the table from Angela.  The five boys may be seated in $5!$ ways as we proceed clockwise around the table from Angela.  Hence, there are $4!5!$ distinguishable seating arrangements.

Comment: I drew out some of the possible arrangements and I can see why I was wrong. I didn't think of locking in 1 person in 1 of the seats so that the symmetrical arrangements are not taken into account. I thought of it in a slightly different way which is what led to the incorrect solution.

Comment: I can see why, if you solve it the way I did above, you have to divide by 5 in the end because if every person moves 2 seats to their left or right (doesn't matter which way) you produce symmetrical arrangements and this can happen 5 times as there are 10 seats which we do not want. Moving every person 1 seat to their left or right produces some unique and some symmetrical arrangements which is why it is incorrect to divide by 10.